# Can I bind to in indexer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to bind incoming HTTP data to an indexer.

For example, if I have

```
[HttpPost]public void Test ([Binding Include="MyProp"]MyClass p) ...
```

and MyClass defines MyProp, everything work.

However, what if I want to get additional data that's not defined as a property?

For example, if I have

```
[HttpPost]public void Test ([Binding Include="MyProp, OtherProp"]MyClass p) ...
```

and

MyClass has defines an indexer, I'd like the MVC runtime to call

```
p["OtherProp"] = someValue
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is nothing built in allowing you to achieve this. One way to achieve this would be to write a custom model binder for the `MyClass` type.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would need. How do I create a custom model binder?

Comment: @user380719, there are many tutorials on the internet about writing custom models binders. The process consists in implementing the IModelBinder interface or deriving from the DefaultModelBinder class. Here's one such article: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/05/05/iterating-on-an-asp-net-mvc-model-binder.aspx